# Using compiler constants in build events

Tags: .net, visual-studio, post-build-event, compile-time-constant

Is there anyway to use compiler constants in Build Events in Visual Studio - VB.NET? (especially in Post-Build events)

**Scenario**

If `TEST_EDITION=TRUE` is defined I want to run an executable during the Post-Build event so if it's `FALSE` then I'll run something else.

This can be used for creating different installers for different editions.

*P.S. Before someone suggests: No I don't want to use nant, msbuild or something like that*

Comment: It would help if you'd explain more about what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to write a conditional build-event based on the compiler constant? Wasn't that clear? -but I added an example to clear that up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the $(DefineConstants) macro is available and can be tested in a build event.  For example, Project + Compile, Advanced Compile Options, Custom constants = Test can be tested like this:

```
if /i "$(DefineConstants)" NEQ "TEST" goto skiptest
echo Setting up for test environment
:skiptest
```

More complicated custom constants like Test=TRUE or compound constants need to be parsed differently.  Admittedly I quickly gave up trying to figure out how to use the horrid [FOR command.](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Visual Basic's syntax, but the following trick can be used by C++: the file global_inc.bat reads as:

```
SET PARAMETER=TRUE
```

This could be input by a batch script which was called in post-build event.
The C++ code used the file as follows:

```
#define PARAMETER const int parameter
#define SET /**/
#include "global_inc.bat"
;
#undef PARAMETER
```

The postbuild step looked like this:

```
call global_inc.bat
if "%PARAMETER%" == "TRUE" echo True
```

---

Another possibility would be for the prebuild step to *generate* a `.vb` file, as well as a configuration file used in postbuild step.

Comment: I assume this is your workaround for this limitation, because I don't really need to compile anything. All I want to do this run an executable only when a constant is TRUE during the post-build event.

Comment: changed the example to be closer to the question. the answer by nobugz seems me a better solution however

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the MsBuild PostEvents? this is an extract of a .csproj... but the same applies to vbproj files

```
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).dll" DestinationFolder="$(BinariesFolder)" ContinueOnError="true" />
  </Target>
```

You can use it with the [TaskExec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) Target, which allows you to run a batch file or an executable.

```
<Target Name="DoSomething">
    <Exec Command="D:\DoSomething.exe"/>
</Target>
```

Comment: I don't want to use msbuild because it's not suitable for our current build server setup.

Comment: Also I'm not even quite sure if Msbuild supports this.

Comment: There is an ExecTask for MsBuild which allows you to run a Batch file or Executable... I've updated my answer